# MySQL commenting out alter table partition statement

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table that is empty for now but will be loaded with hundreds of millions of records. Before I do this load, I want to create some partitions on the table to improve query performance and to enable better deletion later on (just truncate an entire partition).

The alter table code I am using is:

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME` 
 PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(DATE_FIELD)) (
 PARTITION y1 VALUES LESS THAN (2017),
 PARTITION y2 VALUES LESS THAN (2018),
 PARTITION y3 VALUES LESS THAN (2019),
 PARTITION ymax VALUES LESS THAN (2050)
 );
```

When I run the code in MySQL Workbench, it executes fine without any errors. when I inspect the table, the partitions do not show up in the list:
[image]

and in the auto generated DDL, the partition is commented out:

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME` (
  `field1` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_FIELD` date NOT NULL,
  `field3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `field4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `field5` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `field6` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field6`,`DATE_FIELD`),
  KEY `dd_IDX1` (`DATE_FIELD`,`field1`,`field2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (year(`DATE_FIELD`))
(PARTITION y1 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y3 VALUES LESS THAN (2019) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION ymax VALUES LESS THAN (2050) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

I cannot figure out why this would be. I loaded some fake records to see if the lack of data was causing the issue. I also tried commenting out the partitions and created a new table with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I am going to chalk up the fact that the partitions do not show up in the Partitions screen when clicking Table Inspector to a bug in the GUI. When you select Alter Table and look at the partitioning tab, they show up there. Additionally, when checking the `PARTITIONS` information table the partitions show up there as well. See Rick James answer to understand the comment syntax.

Comment: Use the commandline "mysql" tool.  In it do `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name\G` to see the full definition.

Answer (score 2):

`/*!50100 ... */` is a special type of comment.  It says "If the version is 5.1.0 or later, include the text as real; else leave it as just a comment.

So, if you ran this on a 5.0 server, it would not have partitions.  (5.0 did not have `PARTITIONs` implemented.)  But 5.1 and later will.

You will see variations on this in `mysqldump` output.

Meanwhile, you will probably find that you gain no performance by using `PARTITIONing`.  What were you hoping for?

Comment: Admittedly the table is not fully loaded yet, but I actually do think I have see some performance improvements. 1. I am using a python script to load the table. The user can pass a year and the script will truncate that partition, then reload data into that partition. Before, deletes for a year took forever. 2. All queries will have a date or date range on them, and the explain plan shows that the SQL engine is only reading from the necessary partition. I am not a DBA but I think this means that it is not scanning over the other unnecessary rows. Feel free to comment if I am missing something.

Comment: Are you inserting one `INSERT` at a time?  There are ways to significantly speed that up.  (Batch inserts, `LOAD DATA`, transactions, etc).  Your current question only asks about the "comment".  Start a new Question if you need to discuss performance.

Comment: I am indeed doing bulk inserts into the DB. Python performance is fine and I think DB performance is fine for now (will know more once fully loaded). I will know more and will open a different question up at a later date if I need to. You are correct, my initial question was only for the partition not showing up on certain screens and understanding the comment.